# Overriding osmdroid MapView’s Default Pan/move

Tags: android, android-mapview, osmdroid, touch-event, panning

I have mapView and I programatically handle the touch events.

The problem is: if the mapview is ZoomOut to its maximum, the panning is quite small and slow, and conforming the mapView is ZoomIn, the panning is bigger and faster. In another words: bigger the zoomIN bigger the panning movements.

How can I make panning moves not accordingly to zoom , so every time I move the map, it moves the same distance no matter the zoom level?
or is there another way to override panning in mapview?

Here is my android Client

```
private double savedTouchedX = -1;
private double savedTouchedY = -1;
....

mapView.setOnTouchListener(new MapView.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent event) {
            int action = event.getAction();
            final Projection pj = mapView.getProjection();
            GeoPoint eventPosition = (GeoPoint) pj.fromPixels((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());

             switch(action)
             {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    savedTouchedX = eventPosition.getLongitude();
                    savedTouchedY = eventPosition.getLatitude();
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    doPanning(eventPosition, mapView);
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    doPanning(eventPosition, mapView);
                    savedTouchedX = -1;
                    savedTouchedY = -1;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
             }
             return true;
        }
    });

//move mapView
private boolean doPanning(GeoPoint e, MapView mapView)
 {
        GeoPoint mapCenter = (GeoPoint) mapView.getMapCenter();
        GeoPoint panToCenter = new GeoPoint((int)(mapCenter.getLatitudeE6() + (e.getLatitude() - savedTouchedY) * 1E5),
        (int)(mapCenter.getLongitudeE6() - (e.getLongitude() - savedTouchedX) * 1E5));
        mapView.getController().setCenter(panToCenter);
    savedTouchedX = e.getLongitude();
    savedTouchedY = e.getLatitude();
    return true;
 }
```

Comment: You could probably use `setOnDragListener` of MapView maybe helpful.
Otherwise you could use GeoLocations to pan in steps. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks @zIronManBox .I updated my code above implementing GeoLocations, but map pans opposite to the mouse direction. If I move it up, it goes down, if I move it right, it goes left. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You MUST transform your MotionEvent position (which is in screen coords) in a Map position. 
This is not the same coordinates system at all!

```
final Projection pj = mapView.getProjection();
GeoPoint eventPosition = (GeoPoint) pj.fromPixels((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
```

Comment: Thanks @Mker .I updated my code above implementing this, but **map pans opposite to the mouse direction**.  If I move it up, it goes down, if I move it right, it goes left. Is there something wrong with my implementation?

Comment: Actually they have panning has a weird behavior

Comment: You are currently mixing getLatitudeE6 and e.getLatitude()*1E5. And once you add, once you substract... "GeoPoint panToCenter = new GeoPoint(mapCenter.getLatitude() + e.getLatitude() - savedTouchedY, mapCenter.getLongitude() + e.getLongitude() - savedTouchedX);" should be better.